# How to use numeric user id with next-auth

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I recently found and started testing [create-t3-app](https://create.t3.gg/) as a new base for NextJS projects because it takes care of a lot of boilerplate setup for things like TypeScript, trpc, prisma, and next-auth so it'd save me a ton of time. While that's relevant, I don't think it's the source of my problem. My problem is that I use a MySQL database with auto-incrementing user IDs but it seems like the types for the `next-auth` package are forcing me to use a string (`DefaultUser` in `next-auth/core/types.d.ts` and `AdapterUser` in `next-auth/adapters.d.ts` both set the type of id to string and the comments say UUIDs). Thinking that I could possibly extend what's there to support numeric user IDs, I added this to `next-auth.d.ts`:

```
import { DefaultSession, DefaultUser } from 'next-auth'

declare module 'next-auth' {
  interface User extends DefaultUser {
    id: number;
  }
  interface Session {
    user?: {
      id: number;
    } & DefaultSession['user'];
  }
}
```

Which seems to work most places except in `[...nextauth].ts` where it is giving me this error

> Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)

On the `session.user.id = user.id` line in this section of code

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // Include user.id on session
  callbacks: {
    session({ session, user }) {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.id = user.id
      }
      return session
    }
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: []
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

The TypeScript error goes away if I delete the `id: string;` line from the `AdapterUser` from `next-auth/adapters.d.ts` which then falls back to `id: number;` because I set that on `User`

```
export interface AdapterUser extends User {
    id: string; // <-- I removed this
    email: string;
    emailVerified: Date | null;
}
```

I don't think I should have to modify the library's types to support numeric user IDs but I'm all out of ideas how to solve this and haven't found answers online. Or should I not be using numeric IDs even though my database does? If it helps, I'm using

```
next 12.3.1
next-auth 4.12.3
react 18.2.0
react-dom 18.2.0
superjson 1.9.1
zod 3.18.0
eslint 8.22.0
postcss 8.4.14
prettier 2.7.1
prisma 4.4.0
tailwindcss 3.1.6
typescrypt 4.8.0
```

Comment: Why not stringify the ids?

Comment: @caTS Seemed seemed as hacky as my current solution with extra operations especially considering the documentation and comments suggest the ids are intended to be UUIDs.

Comment: @DillanWilding UUID are string like "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000".
Did you try to declare `User.id` as `number | string` and update comparison with `... = parseInt(user.id, 10)`

Comment: @IQbrod I know what UUIDs are. The problem isn't that the id on `User` isn't numeric (or strings), it's that the TypeScript types `next-auth` has provided has propagated the user id type throughout their other types such as `AdapterUser` (and I think a couple other places) which is causing problems when I want to change it to a numeric value. If they didn't specify the type of id when extending `User`, it'd default/fallback to the one specified on `User` but since they say `id: string;` it causes problems.

Comment: @dillanwilding you should consider opening an issue and/or a pull request on their project beacuse there is no way to fix this without updating library's code

Comment: @IQbrod I was debating about doing that but since I'm relatively new to TypeScript and Next, I wasn't sure if I'd have anything valuable to contribute so I thought I'd check if anyone on StackOverflow could help first. Doesn't seem likely since even with putting a bounty on this question only 50 people have seen it in 4 days.

Comment: @DillanWilding Did you ever open an issue for this? Running into the same problem where my Prisma User `id` is of type `number`, but module augmentation only allows me to merge the default NextAuth User from `id: string` into `id: string | number`... TypeScript's problem is there's no way to overwrite an interface's properties, you can only merge definitions

Comment: @Girrafish I had been putting it off because I didn't think many people encountered the issue and didn't want to embarrass myself with a stupid question/suggestion but I just created an issue https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7966 Hopefully they can help us more and we can get a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to "patch up" or change the types the library has - even trying to change `NextAuthOptions` doesn't work since subsequent property definitions must have the same type. In the meantime, you'll have to use a runtime check/coercion or cast:

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // Include user.id on session
  callbacks: {
    session({ session, user }) {
      if (session.user) {
        if (typeof user.id !== "number") throw new Error("id should a number");
        session.user.id = user.id // OK
        // session.user.id = +user.id // more dangerous but still works
        // session.user.id = user.id as number // also dangerous
      }
      return session
    }
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: []
}
```

Comment: First off, thanks for following up. While this technically gets rid of the TypeScript error, I'm curious if there's a better solution -- if I don't get one, I'll award your answer the bounty as it does solve my problem just not the way I'd like. I now see the problem is that I was under the impression that if I implemented `User` that extended `DefaultUser` and specified `id: number` that it doesn't overwrite it, it acts as a union (i.e. `string | number`). Any idea if there's a way to replace the type instead of making a union?

Comment: @DillanWilding That's the thing - you can't. Subsequent declarations of a member must be of the exact same type; in other words, you can't make the type narrower or overwrite it. This is the best workaround until the library authors provide a way to augment their types.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the above accepted answer, I utilized runtime typeguards to make my life a little easier.

In my case, my Prisma user had a few extra attributes as well:

```
model User {
  id                  Int                 @id @default(autoincrement())
  uuid                String              @unique @default(cuid())
  name                String?
  email               String?             @unique
  emailVerified       DateTime?
  image               String?
  accounts            Account[]
  categories          Category[]
  sessions            Session[]
  records             Record[]
  permissionsGranted  SharePermission[]     @relation("permissions_granted")
  permissionsReceived SharePermission[]     @relation("permissions_received")
  @@unique([id, uuid])
  @@index(fields: [id, uuid], name: "user_by_id_idx")
}
```

So I defined these typeguards:

```
import { User as PrismaUser } from '@prisma/client';
import { Session, User } from 'next-auth';

export interface IdentifiedSession extends Session {
    id: number;
    user: PrismaUser;
}

export const isNextAuthUser = (value: unknown): value is User => {
    const { id, name, email, image } = (value ?? {}) as User;
    const idIsValid = typeof id === 'number';
    const nameIsValid = typeof name === 'string' || !name;
    const emailIsValid = typeof email === 'string' || !email;
    const imageIsValid = typeof image === 'string' || !image;
    return idIsValid && nameIsValid && emailIsValid && imageIsValid;
};

export const isPrismaUser = (value: unknown): value is PrismaUser => {
    const { uuid, emailVerified } = (value ?? {}) as PrismaUser;
    const uuidIsValid = typeof uuid === 'string';
    const emailVerifiedIsEmail = emailVerified instanceof Date || !emailVerified;
    return isNextAuthUser(value) && uuidIsValid && emailVerifiedIsEmail;
};

export const isSession = (value: unknown): value is Session => {
    const { user, expires } = (value ?? {}) as Session;
    const userIsValid = isPrismaUser(user) || isNextAuthUser(user) || !user;
    const expiresIsValid = typeof expires === 'string';
    return expiresIsValid && userIsValid;
};

export const isIdentifiedSession = (value: unknown): value is IdentifiedSession => {
    const session = (value ?? {}) as IdentifiedSession;
    const sessionIsValid = isSession(session);
    const sessionUserIsValid = isPrismaUser(session.user);
    return sessionIsValid && sessionUserIsValid;
};
```

Then, in the session callback, I utilized one of the typeguards like so:

```
session: async ({ session, user }) => {
  if (!isPrismaUser(user)) {
    return session;
  }
  const identifiedSession: IdentifiedSession = {
    ...session,
    user,
    id: user.id,
  };
  return identifiedSession;
}
```

Which does mean that the signature of the callback is now `Session | IdentifiedSession`, which I handle in downstream consumers as such

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ req, res }) => {
    const session = await getSession({ req });
    if (!isIdentifiedSession(session)) {
        return {
            props: {
                records: [],
            },
        };
    }
    const records = await prisma.record.findMany({
        where: {
            reporter: {
                id: session.id,
            },
        },
        orderBy: {
            date: 'asc',
        },
        include: {
            category: {
                select: {
                    title: true,
                },
            },
        },
    });
    return {
        props: { records },
    };
};
```